# How can I connect back to home based network

Tags: networking

I was having problems with my modem for my home internet. I pressed the reset button. Now its connected to hotpoint network which is not working. Please help. How do I set it back to my home Internet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve hit the rest button on the router/modem then you’ll need to re-configure it again. It’s a hard reset used for screwed up configs.

You’ll need to get your details from your ISP or simply call them for support.

Assuming you’ve hit the hard reset button and not just a power-cycle one...

Comment: Yeah if you’ve got the details at home then feel free to re-configure or speak to the ISP when they’re open.